# Что лучше использовать в mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Что лучше и быстрее?

Миллион записей в одной таблице или по 400 записей в 2500 таблицах? Для справки - я хочу инвентарь каждого пользователя хранить в отдельных таблицах или всё в одну сгружать и вытаскивать по id пользователя?

Comment: я, конечно, не эксперт. но нужны очень весомые аргументы, чтобы каждому пользователю создавать свой набор таблиц. а миллион записей это не такое и большое число.

Comment: Цифру миллион взял для примера,может быть и более.Ну например эти данные постоянно удаляются и снова заносятся. Помоему лучше тогда обновлять в отдельной таблице,чем в одной огромной

Comment: *миллион записей в одной таблице или по 400 записей в 2500 таблицах?* Каждая таблица, кроме первой - это грабли. Тебе нужны 2499 заботливо разложенных на своём пути граблей?

Comment: Ну так постоянно будет происходить манипуляция с данными(удаление и снова занесение). Не будет ли это тормозить Select? +айди будет бесконечно расти. При этом может быть что не только 1 пользователь будет производить манипуляции...

Comment: @hunter, обычно все что часто меняется лучше выносить в отдельную таблицу и делать привязку к записи

Comment: это не имеет значения, потому что другого пути кроме как 1 таблицы нет. если боитесь исчерпания id, сделайте его bigint. Представьте, что вам надо найти всех пользователей у которых есть в инвентаре X. Как вы это сделаете если у вас 2500 таблиц

Comment: @Mike юнион на 2500 таблиц :D

Comment: @Mike а что на счет Select, манипуляции и Select будут одновременно выполняться?

Comment: @hunter А что такое "манипуляции" ?

Comment: @Mike удаление и снова внесение данных

Comment: @hunter А зачем удалять и снова вносить данные. удалять лучше то, чего больше нет, добавлять только новое, а существующее, но например изменившее количество обновлять (update). Удаление заблокирует страницы индекса с удаляемыми записями. могут быть некоторые проблемы в select близких в индексе значений. значит надо что бы операции изменения проходили быстро. а вообще если есть опасения что будут проблемы с блокировками лучше заменить СУБД на postrgesql, в нем блокировки на уровне записей и нет влияния на смежные области таблиц.

Comment: @Mike спасибо,тоесть для высоконагруженного проекта,лучше сразу на Postgresql ?

Comment: @hunter Ну это можно бесконечно обсуждать достоинства и недостатки разных БД. У всех БД есть сильные стороны и слабые. Но да, лучше НЕ MySQL. postgresql как вариант. у него и возможностей гораздо больше. ту же операцию вставить-изменить-удалить (т.е. довести до актуального состояния) можно вообще за 1 запрос сделать. А высоконагруженные проекты это вообще отдельная песня. там одной реляционной СУБД обычно не достаточно, для каких то задач может быть нужно noSQL

Comment: @Mike postgress сильно уступает mysql в скорости репликации данных. Но это не тот случай кмк

Comment: Очень интересно посмотреть на join с 2.5к таблиц. ИМХО проблема надуманная

Comment: Проще использовать NoSQL

Answer (score 3):

Если вы беспокоитесь, что ваша таблица с миллионом записей будет перегружена - то вы волнуетесь зря! MySQL умеет работать с миллионами записей.

Вот несколько советов, если вам необходимо работать с большими данными:

- Используйте индексы. Индексы усложняют вставку, но упрощают выборку. С ним ваши select/delete запросы будут быстрее.
- Разбивайте ваши крупные select-выборки на чанки в вашем приложении. Например, php-массив в 300 000 записей из БД занимал у меня 250мб памяти. Разбиение на маленькие группы данных при помощи OFFSET LIMIT позволили мне сохранить память и не так сильно нагружать БД.
- Если вы предполагаете, что работа с миллионами записей у вашего приложения будет нормой - посмотрите в сторону MongoDB, она лучше справляется с большими данными, но хуже с меньшими.
- Почитайте про [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html), [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), если вас интересуют подробности больших select и insert запросов.

Соглашусь с sanmai и добавлю ещё один момент. Определённо, вам не нужно создавать такое огромное количество таблиц: кроме нерациональности , это сильно усложняет логику работы приложения (когда создавать новые таблицы, поддержание связей между таблиц в актуальном состоянии). Попробуйте использовать связующие таблицы, которые будут хранить связь между пользователем и его предметом. 1 связь - 1 запись.

Comment: "Если вы предполагаете, что работа с миллионами записей у вашего приложения будет нормой - посмотрите в сторону MongoDB, она лучше справляется с большими данными, но хуже с меньшими."  Утверждение голословно и не правильно.

Comment: @MikeSprindzhuk на MongoDB имеет реальный смысл переходить, когда уже как минимум серверный БД кластер имеется. если проект умещается и на одном сервере, то лучше используйте MySQL/MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

Каждая новая таблица расходует ресурс сервера на поддержание открытого файла. Даже если вы настроите `open_files_limit` при помощи обычного метода, ресурсы сервера все равно будут использоваться под вещи, которые не нужны. Кроме того, интересно может повести себя буферный пул. Потому, если вы не знаете что так точно будет хуже, лучше однородные данные в пределах одного сервера держать в одной таблице.

Миллион записей — это пустяки в наши дни.

Comment: а если например будет 10 миллиардов записей?

Comment: @hunter до 100 млн. можете смело все хранить в одной таблице, если больше - можно подумать над распределением нагрузки (но свыше 100 млн. там и так придется делать шардинг, т.к. даже одна таблица будет много весить).